# react-express application to Azure?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure, express

I'm trying to deploy my react-express application to Azure.

My code is in client and server directories. I have tried to deploy by using Azure Static Web application without success
[image: Application structure:]
[image: .yml file:]
[image: ci: add Azure Static Workflow file:]
I'm using node v18.19.0.

What is wrong with the settings? I can't see my application after deployment in the address where it is supposed to be - link is showing only Azure's 'default page': https://lemon-dune-05f7fbe03.4.azurestaticapps.net/

Comment: You have given very little information to go on, but from what I can tell, you are trying to deploy to Azure static suing GitHub Actions?

However I assume that your server is what serves the static files, and since you are deploying only static files, your server will not be running to serve the static files.

It also doesn't look like your GitHub Actions are running any kind of build step, so even if it normally outputs some static files, you aren't doing that before trying to put it on Azure, so even if your server were running, there's nothing for it to serve.

Comment: @Suvisohvi please share the code

Comment: Here is the link to the code: https://github.com/mipirine/marketenergia

Comment: @Sampath github.com/mipirine/marketenergia

Comment: @Makure conver the back end code to azure function code.staticwebapp.config.json```{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html",
    "exclude": ["*.{css,scss,js,png,gif,ico,jpg,svg}"]
  }
}``` . For more details you try this sample [example](https://github.com/Sampath280/ravi44)

Comment: If don't want to change the code. Make sure to deploy back end and front end separate.use back end url in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Publish an API to Azure Static Web [Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/publish-static-web-app-api-preview-url/)

[image]
The code below is for fetching electricity price data from an API and displaying it in a React app using Google Charts
App.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";
import axios from 'axios';

export const options = {
  title: "Pörssisähkön hinta, 7vk [c/kWh]",
  width: 1600,
  height: 800,
  bar: { groupWidth: "95%" },
  legend: { position: "none" },
};

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/data")
    .then(response => {
      setData(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching data from the server:', error.message);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log('data: ', data);

   return (
    <Chart
      chartType="ColumnChart"
      width="100%"
      height="400px"
      data={data}
      options={options}
    />
  ); 
}
```

Create a Static web app with a serverless [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/how-to/with-web-app/static-web-app-with-swa-cli).

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_THANKFUL_FOREST_096B1E810 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "client" # App source code path
          api_location: "server" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "build" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_THANKFUL_FOREST_096B1E810 }}
          action: "close"
```

**Pacakage.json:**

```
"build-prod": "cd client && npm install && npm update && npm run build && cd .. && npm install && npm update && npm run build"
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks :-) . I'm still struggling with this even though I have followed the instructions. I'll try to continue tomorrow. What node version you are using? 14?

Comment: Follow these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/publish-static-web-app-api-preview-url/). node 18

Comment: I have followed your latest instructions, and I have changed to node 18. But I'm not able to deploy to Azure even a Static Web Application - in VScode Production main (WaitingForDeployment) and github actions are failing. I'm trying this example in Windows environment. I'm wondering if I'm missing some settings in VScode...

Comment: Updated. Make sure to convert the server side/API code to function app v3/deploy back end and front end separately. use the back-end URL in the front end. I followed the back end and front end separately.

Comment: I finally managed to deploy the code to Azure: https://black-plant-0e14d4c03.4.azurestaticapps.net/ by using Azure functions. Thank you very much :-)